# Xubuntu18.04: Odys Winbook 13 touchpad not working

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, touchpad, 64-bit

Odys Winbook13 is one of the many MacBook clones with the Intel N3450 CPU.

I added a 240 GB SSD to the system. I've smoothly installed Xubuntu 18.04.1 in dual boot with Windows 10. Everything is working apart the touchpad that does not appear to be detected by the OS.

Googling around, in a redhat distro forum, I've found that the problem (at least in Fedora) is the Odys Winbook 13 uses a SIPODEV SP1064 touchpad, which does not supply descriptors. The author of the post suggests a solution, a patch to be added to the DMI descriptor override list, fixing the touchpad not working.

Unfortunately, I'm a total newbie and I can only vaguely figure out what this means. How can I do this on Ubuntu?

Here the link to the original post:
https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg59330.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Ukuu and install kernel 5.0. It includes the necessary fixes for the Winbook 13. [Here](https://www.ostechnix.com/ukuu-an-easy-way-to-install-and-upgrade-linux-kernel-in-ubuntu-based-systems/) is how it works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please give more information on how to do this?